# System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.3.0'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm receiving the following warning on my ASP.NET Core 2.1 MVC project.

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.DefaultItems.targets(153,5):
>   warning NETSDK1071: A PackageReference to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App'
>   specified a Version of `2.1.7`. Specifying the version of this package
>   is not recommended. For more information, see
>   https://aka.ms/sdkimplicitrefs

It appears to be referencing this line in my `.csproj` file:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.7" />
```

If I remove the version from the PackageReference the warning goes away, but then I get this error when I try to start my project:

> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.3.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest
>   definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> File name: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
>
> at MyProject.Web.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services)
>
> at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

I'm not sure where `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=2.1.3.0` is even coming from. Anyone else run into the same problem?

Comment: I too have this issue and was able to resolve it by adding the version to that package reference like  `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" Version="2.1.3" />`

Comment: @Wellspring, Add your `.csproj` file code. I am telling you what the problem exactly is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure what caused the problem, but to fix it I went ahead and updated from `ASP.NET Core 2.1` to `2.2` by following this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/21-to-22?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio).

Here's the relevant part of my `.csproj` after the update:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <!-- Other Unrelated Packages Here -->

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />

    <!-- Other Unrelated  Packages Here -->
</ItemGroup>
```

Then, I updated all of my NuGet packages to the latest version.

I imagine there's a solution without having to upgrade versions of `ASP.NET Core`, but since I don't have any reason not to upgrade, this is what I did to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.7.0" newVersion="2.1.7.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `TargetFramework` was different between two projects (`net6.0` and `.net7.0`):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
         ...
```